# Swagger login "User not found" Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, swagger

When I try to log in in Postman, everything works fine, but in Swagger UI I'm constantly getting the "user not found" error even though it is existing user. I think I'm missing something and I cannot figure out what it might be. Any help anyone?

[image: screenshot]

Swagger.json:

```json
"/user/login": {
          "post": {
            "tags": ["User"],
            "summary": "User login",
            "produces": "application/json",
            "consumes": "application/json",
            "parameters": [
              {
                "in": "body",
                "name": "body",
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/userSchema",
                  "type": "object", // tried "string" also
                  "properties": {
                    "email": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "password": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                },
                "required": {
                  "email": true,
                  "password": true
                }
              }
            ],
            "responses": {
              "201": {
                "description": "OK"
              }
            }
          }
        }

 ...
 "securitySchemes": {
    "bearerAuth": {
      "type": "http",
      "scheme": "bearer",
      "bearerFormat": "JWT"
    }
  },

  "security": {
    "bearerAuth": []
  }
```

Response received in Swagger UI:

```
{
  "error": "User not found!"
}
```

App code:

```js
import "babel-polyfill";
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

import userRoute from "./route/user";
import layoutRoute from "./route/layout";
import categoryRoute from "./route/category";
import postRoute from "./route/post";
import commentRoute from "./route/comment";
import forecastRoute from "./route/forecast";
import currencyRoute from "./route/currencyRates";
import statsRoute from "./route/stats";
import contactRoute from "./route/contactUs";
import rateLimit from "express-rate-limit";
import { machineId } from "node-machine-id";
import swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import * as swaggerDoc from "./swagger.json";

require("dotenv").config();
const { PORT, MONGODB_USER, MONGODB_PASS, ENV, MONGODB_SERVER } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const corsOptions = {
  exposedHeaders: "Authorization"
};

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 60 * 1000,
  max: 3,
  skipSuccessfulRequests: true,
  windowMs: 1000 * 60 * 1
});

app.use("/user/login", limiter);

app.use("/masina", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(await machineId());
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.static("public/static/images"));

app.use("/swagger", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerDoc));
app.use("/user", userRoute);
app.use("/layout", layoutRoute);
app.use("/category", categoryRoute);
app.use("/post", postRoute);
app.use("/comment", commentRoute);
app.use("/forecast", forecastRoute);
app.use("/currencyRates", currencyRoute);
app.use("/", statsRoute);
app.use("/", contactRoute);

//  ERROD MIDDLEWARE
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
});

const mongodbDev = `mongodb://localhost:27017/news`;
const mongodbProd = `mongodb://${MONGODB_USER}:${MONGODB_PASS}@localhost:27017/news`;

mongoose
  .connect(ENV === "DEV" ? mongodbDev : mongodbProd, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`App is online on port ${PORT}`);
    app.listen(PORT);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error occured. Shuting down.");
    console.log("ERROR ", err);
    process.exit();
  });
```

Comment: Please post your server code. Does the specified user actually exist in your DB?

Comment: @Helen User exists in db,i tested that in postman. Code is added. Thank you (:

Comment: @StefanStanković Hey , can you add in your code from `"./route/user"` ?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha Where exactly ? Thank you for answering (: